# reading numbers from text into variables in python

Tags: python

assume i have a text file that only has the following format where each line has two numbers separated by a space:

```
2 4
66 99
11 67
1 3
```

this is my code which i tried doing:

```
with open('text_file.txt') as file:
    lines = []
    for i in file:
        lines.append(i)
    print(lines)
```

the problem with my code is that it keeps printing "\n" with the numbers and i don't know how to get around that
i need a way to read only the two numbers in the last line and store each number in a variable, so for the example above:

`var1 = 1` , `var2 = 3`.

i need this for a multi-threading program , where i am testing a "race condition" between three threads where each thread reads the last two numbers in the text file and read the last line of numbers, and then  print the thread_ip in the first ,and increment the second from the previous last line and print it.

im not asking for help for the whole assignment, just the reading/writing the text file part is what i can't seem to figure out.

Comment: _just the reading/writing the text file part is what i can't seem to figure out._ There are mountains of information available on the topic, does none of it cover this particular situation?

Comment: no, if hadn't already been on google for two hours now , i wouldn't have posted a question

Comment: Alright, can you be more specific, then? _i need this for a multi-threading program , where i am testing a "race condition" between three threads where each thread reads the last two numbers in the text file and read the last line of numbers, and then print the thread_ip in the first ,and increment the second from the previous last line and print it._ Can you expand on that? I think it's worth considering the larger problem here.

Comment: Have you succeeded in writing code that reads from a file *at all*? If so, what does your code specifically not do that it needs to do?

Comment: i don't want to seem like a lazy person to ask for the code for the entire problem , i just need help to know how i can read text files the way i need.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel i edited the post to contain my code which didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("example_file", "r") as fin:
   var1, var2 = [int(i) for i in fin.readline().split()]
```

To store the last two numbers in the last line:

```
with open("example_file", "r") as fin:
   var1, var2 = [int(i) for i in fin.readlines()[-1].split()]
```

Comment: this stores the first two numbers in the variables , how can i change it so it can store the last two numbers in the laast line?

Comment: @R00 I edited the answer. If this helped, could you please accept it by clicking the checkmark? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So both of the examples in the currently accepted answer from izhang work, but they come with a cost... In the first example, you have to needlessly walk the entire file to come to the last line. And in the second example, you have to read the entire file into memory. If dealing with large datasets, and/or running inside of constrained containers, this will absolutely become a problem.

The better solution is to read the file backwards and break after the first read line. This is not an easy task to do from scratch, but fortunately, there is a module for that.

```py
from file_read_backwards import FileReadBackwards

with FileReadBackwards('text_file.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        var1, var2 = l.split()
        break
print(var1, var2)
```